# pretty_breaks function trows an error

Tags: r, ggplot2

**The Goal I am trying to achieve**

I have two dataframes that I want to plot them overlayed/superimposed for the group variables. The variables are grouped gender and age band and I have Count in each dataframe. I am working only with `tidyverse` and `ggplot2`.

```
ae_att_df <- structure(list(Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = 
                      c("Female", "Male", "Not Specified"), class = "factor"), 
             AgeBand = structure(1:10, .Label = c("0 yrs", "1-4 yrs", "10-14 
                                       yrs", "15- 19 yrs", "20-24 yrs", "25- 
                            29 yrs", "30-34 yrs", "35-39 yrs", "40-44 yrs", 
                            "45-49 yrs", "5-9 yrs", "50-54 yrs", "55-59 yrs", 
                          "60-64 yrs", "65-69 yrs", "70-74 yrs", "75-79 yrs", 
                          "80-84 yrs", "85+ yrs"), class = "factor"), N = 
                     c(4708L, 7065L, 1914L, 2292L, 4612L, 5968L, 5620L, 
                       4007L, 2802L, 2429L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class 
                  = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = 
       "Gender", drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:9), group_sizes = 10L, 
                                                           biggest_group_size 
                                             = 10L, labels = structure(list(
        Gender = structure(1L, .Label = c("Female", "Male", "Not Specified"), 
             class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = 
             "data.frame", vars = "Gender", drop = TRUE))

ae_adm_df <- structure(list(Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = 
                                 c("Female", "Male", "Not Specified"), class 
                                   = "factor"), 
                     AgeBand = structure(1:10, .Label = c("0 yrs", "1-4 yrs", 
                      "10-14 yrs", "15-19 yrs", "20-24 yrs", "25-29 yrs", 
                       "30-34 yrs", "35-39 yrs", "40-44 yrs", "45-49 yrs", 
                       "5-9 yrs", "50-54 yrs", "55-59 yrs", "60-64 yrs", "65- 
                       69 yrs", "70-74 yrs", "75-79 yrs", "80-84 yrs", "85+ 
                      yrs"), class = "factor"), N = c(4352L, 6229L, 2145L, 
                       2328L, 3963L, 4769L, 4475L, 3342L, 2544L, 2141L)), 
                       row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                   "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                 vars = "Gender", drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:9), 
                 group_sizes = 10L, biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = 
                 structure(list(Gender = structure(1L, .Label = c("Female", 
                                                "Male", "Not Specified"), 
                 class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = 
                "data.frame", vars = "Gender", drop = TRUE))
```

**The Problem I have**

When I am attempting to plot it with 'ggplot2', it trows an error for ***pretty_breaks***.

> Error in pretty_breaks(15) : could not find function "pretty_breaks".

This is the code I have tried:

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x = AgeBand, y = N)) +
geom_bar(data = ae_att_df,  stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', aes(fill = 
                                                                  Gender))+
geom_bar(data = ae_adm_df,  stat = 'identity',position =position_dodge(0.9), 
                            width = 0.6, aes(fill = Gender)) + xlab("Age 
                                                                    Group") +
ylab("ED Attendances and Admissions") + ggtitle(paste("Unscheduled ED 
                                                       Attendance and 
                                                        Admission")) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(15)) +
 scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("Female Admissions" = "coral3", 
                                        "Female Attendances" = "lightcoral", 
                                        "Male Admissions" = "steelblue4", 
                                        "Male Attendances" = "lightblue2"))
```

**The vizualization of my dataframe** should look like this:

[image]

Yet, I have tried the scale library and I get an empty chart.

[image]

Comment: `library(scales)`

Comment: please check if the data you have provided is correct:
I get an error if I try to run `ae_att_df`.
Also the tibble seems to have 38 rows although you only provide 4.

Comment: yes, I actually cut it and changed the values since my data is confidential. But tried the suggestions to the original data and nothing came up within my plot.

Comment: ok I get that,
but than please provide toy data which does not contain 34 empty rows.
Also there seems to be a typo 'ae_att_df' because I get an error when I try to run it.
For example you could use `head(my_df, 10)` to only show the first 10 lines

Comment: I did some re-edits. And hopefully things come better now.

Comment: Re-edits do not seem to work. Still get the error where loading data.

Comment: Hello Adela, aparently I pressed the wrong button in order to accept your suggestions for a good re-edited code. Would you please do it again and I will accept it? Nevertheless, a coma was missing.

Comment: Your sample data is not representative as it in both cases includes only `Female` in `Gender`. I'll provide some sample data in answer and show you how to make desired plot.

Comment: I know, is just that if I do some edits on my reproducible code then I get other errors.With this comes also the confidentiality of data. And the desired plot is just an example. Otherwise I would know how to do the changes if the output from you guys comes differently.

Comment: @ Adela, I do get what you mean now. Apologies for my comment above in which  I imply different stuff. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need some representative sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
ae_adm_df <- data.frame("Gender" = rep(c("Female Admitted", "Male Admitted"), each = 4),
                        "AgeBand" = rep(c("0 yrs", "1-4yrs", "10-14yrs", "15-19yrs"), 2),
                        "N" = sample(2000:8000, 8))

#   Gender           AgeBand    N
# 1 Female Admitted    0 yrs 3725
# 2 Female Admitted   1-4yrs 6729
# 3 Female Admitted 10-14yrs 4453
# 4 Female Admitted 15-19yrs 7296
# 5   Male Admitted    0 yrs 7639
# 6   Male Admitted   1-4yrs 2273
# 7   Male Admitted 10-14yrs 5165
# 8   Male Admitted 15-19yrs 7349

ae_att_df <- data.frame("Gender" = rep(c("Female Not Admitted", "Male Not Admitted"), each = 4),
                        "AgeBand" = rep(c("0yrs", "1-4yrs", "10-14yrs", "15-19yrs"), 2),
                        "N" = sample(1000:3000, 8))
#                Gender  AgeBand    N
# 1 Female Not Admitted     0yrs 2103
# 2 Female Not Admitted   1-4yrs 1913
# 3 Female Not Admitted 10-14yrs 2912
# 4 Female Not Admitted 15-19yrs 1905
# 5   Male Not Admitted     0yrs 2353
# 6   Male Not Admitted   1-4yrs 2142
# 7   Male Not Admitted 10-14yrs 1205
# 8   Male Not Admitted 15-19yrs 2794
```

Noticed that levels of `Gender` in data `ae_adm_df` differ from levels of `Gender` in `ae_att_df`. This is important.

Now we can plot. Do not include `aes()` in `ggplot()`, as there is no `data` provided. You need to provide `aes(x = AgeBand, fill = Gender, y = N)` for both `geom_bar()` instead.

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = ae_adm_df, aes(x = AgeBand, fill = Gender, y = N), 
           stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  geom_bar(data = ae_att_df, aes(x = AgeBand, y = N, fill = Gender), 
           stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.6) + 
  xlab("Age Group") +
  ylab("ED Attendances and Admissions") + 
  ggtitle("Unscheduled ED Attendance and Admission") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(15)) +
  scale_fill_manual("", values = c("Female Admitted" = "coral3", 
                                   "Female Not Admitted" = "lightcoral", 
                                   "Male Admitted" = "steelblue4", 
                                   "Male Not Admitted" = "lightblue2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Adela. The way you have suggested is good but on different data structure. Anyway, will try to get my data in the structure you have provided. Yet, I have two different columns with A&E attendances which includes the ones Admitted. But the ones admitted appear into another column. Thus, I need to manipulate 3 different columns to design one. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @ Adele - is there a way in ggplot function that I can do the same with my reproduced data set? Why I am insisting on that - it is because I need to count all the attendances to A&E and that comes first in my overlayed plot, and then I add those who were admitted to to hospital from those attending the A&E. That is why your example does not capture too much my problem. Having said that, I am therefore, looking to see whether there is a way to get it with the ggplot applied to my example rather than yours.

Comment: First, your sample data is not representative because it includes only `Female` in `Gender` variable, so it is hard to plot desired output. If I understand correctly, you have one dataset and then you have some subset. In such a case you can create new factor variable to distinguish those who admitted to hospital and who did not. This new factor variable can be used in second `geom_bar` in `fill` argument.

Comment: Hello Adela, I have already indeed solved to problem with the suggested above. Thank you a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

the function `pretty_breaks` is inside the `scales` package.
So you could try

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(15))
```

Or load the whole package at the beginning, using

```
library(scales)
```

Comment: it doesn't plot anything when I add the library(scales).

Comment: and what happens if you use `scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(15))`?